# Выдает ошибку при чтении xml файла(Не допустимый знак для указанной кодировки, строка 3 , позиция 32)

Tags: c#

Выдает исключение при чтении xml файла в строке:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(pathXmlFile);
```

В первом случае выдает ошибку, а во втором нет, разницы  не вижу в названиях пути, все идентично.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report>
    <eeprom version="ENHANCED PBB/ЂB cor/dens v10.12" datetime=""></eeprom>
    <sn>015.15.01.002</sn>
    <file path="\internal\analog.tar" type="tar">
        <point>
            <x>-11,0000000</x>
            <y>1,6000000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>-0,0500000</x>
            <y>0,0000000</y>
        </point>
    </file>
    <file path="\external\density.cor" type="cor">
        <surface>
            <a0>94,5305710</a0>
            <a1>-0,0142365</a1>
            <a2>-0,0043975</a2>
            <a11>-0,0000980</a11>
            <a22>0,0001461</a22>
            <a12>-0,0000220</a12>
            <p>1,0000000</p>
        </surface>
        <surface>
            <a0>-266,8311768</a0>
            <a1>-3,8060381</a1>
            <a2>1,8994861</a2>
            <a11>0,0000000</a11>
            <a22>0,0000000</a22>
            <a12>0,0000000</a12>
            <p>3,0000000</p>
        </surface>
        <surface>
            <a0>0,0000000</a0>
            <a1>0,0000000</a1>
            <a2>0,0000000</a2>
            <a11>-0,0004314</a11>
            <a22>0,0000001</a22>
            <a12>0,0000000</a12>
            <p>6,0000000</p>
        </surface>
        <surface>
            <a0>-13,4954958</a0>
            <a1>0,0428321</a1>
            <a2>-0,0312684</a2>
            <a11>0,0000000</a11>
            <a22>0,0000000</a22>
            <a12>0,0000000</a12>
            <p>7,0000000</p>
        </surface>
        <surface>
            <a0>1000,0000000</a0>
            <a1>0,0000000</a1>
            <a2>100,0000000</a2>
            <a11>0,1000000</a11>
            <a22>10,0000000</a22>
            <a12>0,1000000</a12>
            <p>5,0000000</p>
        </surface>
    </file>
    <file path="\internal\pressure.tar" type="tar">
        <point>
            <x>2360,0000000</x>
            <y>0,0000000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>3532,0000000</x>
            <y>58,4000015</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>4547,0000000</x>
            <y>103,8000031</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>5764,0000000</x>
            <y>158,6999969</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>6877,0000000</x>
            <y>209,0000000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>7900,0000000</x>
            <y>255,1999969</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>8982,0000000</x>
            <y>304,0000000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>10074,0000000</x>
            <y>352,7999878</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>11149,0000000</x>
            <y>400,8999939</y>
        </point>
    </file>
    <file path="\external\density.tar" type="tar">
        <point>
            <x>0,8943808</x>
            <y>0,0000000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0004297</x>
            <y>1,0000000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0124259</x>
            <y>1,1160001</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0233793</x>
            <y>1,2240000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0292079</x>
            <y>1,2840000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0409085</x>
            <y>1,4030000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0498325</x>
            <y>1,4930000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0583036</x>
            <y>1,5800000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0686287</x>
            <y>1,6900001</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0780404</x>
            <y>1,7860010</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0865008</x>
            <y>1,8940001</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0918074</x>
            <y>1,9540000</y>
        </point>
    </file>
    <file path="\external\coriol.tar" type="tar">
        <point>
            <x>0,0000000</x>
            <y>0,0000000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0423599</x>
            <y>8,8731651</y>
        </point>
    </file>
    <file path="\external\rotate.tar" type="tar">
        <point>
            <x>0,2771824</x>
            <y>0,0000000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>51,5987129</x>
            <y>-0,8832195</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>102,9263687</x>
            <y>-2,8315117</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>161,3097382</x>
            <y>-4,0044746</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>203,9690857</x>
            <y>-3,2529044</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>250,3599396</x>
            <y>-4,8435221</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>302,4907227</x>
            <y>-6,9018602</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>351,8223267</x>
            <y>-5,4620886</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>396,1837158</x>
            <y>-6,5484858</y>
        </point>
    </file>
    <file path="\internal\rgr.tar" type="tar">
        <point>
            <x>1,0000000</x>
            <y>0,0000000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,1160051</x>
            <y>-7,7440825</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,2240053</x>
            <y>-4,7421026</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,2839999</x>
            <y>-1,4837382</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,4029999</x>
            <y>0,6799557</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,4930004</x>
            <y>3,0734160</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,5800005</x>
            <y>4,8079190</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,6899979</x>
            <y>6,9035168</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,7860079</x>
            <y>7,7395725</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,8939825</x>
            <y>9,9293804</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,9540000</x>
            <y>8,4871855</y>
        </point>
    </file>
    <file path="\internal\CorKRoP.tar" type="tar">
        <point>
            <x>0,0000000</x>
            <y>1,0000000</y>
        </point>
        <point>
            <x>1,0000000</x>
            <y>1,0000000</y>
        </point>
    </file>
</report>
```

Comment: Ошибка: Не допустимый знак для указанной кодировки, строка 3 , позиция 32

Comment: Каково содержимое XML-файла? Что обозначают два приведённых экранных снимка? Какова фактическая кодировка XML-файла?

Comment: Кодировка - utf - 8 (w\o),  2 снимка обозначают путь к файлу(тип string )

Comment: Тогда добавляйте в вопрос содержимое первого файла. Недопустимый символ находится именно в его содержимом, а не в пути к нему.

Comment: Там какой-то значок Ђ на этом месте где строка 3 , позиция 32

Comment: @ nzeemin А как сделать так чтоб он его пропустил при считывании, или заменил на символ какой то.

Comment: А почему «пропустить»? Почему вам хочется подавить проблему, а не решить?

Comment: У меня ваш код на вашем файле отработал без проблем. В какой кодировке реально ваш файл? Очень похоже на то, что в реальности у вас там не UTF-8.

Comment: На 99% уверен, что файл сохранён не в utf-8. Я уже устал воевать с теми, кто редактирует xml в простых текстовых редакторах типа Notepad (по умолчанию он сохраняет файлы в ANSI).

Comment: @Vlad Я хочу ее решить, вернее нужно решить.

Comment: Кодировка UTF 8(без BOM)

Comment: @SVD102: Странно, ведь ошибка говорит вам, что файл не в этой кодировке.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Решил проблему так:

    StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(pathXmlFile);
    string streamContents;
    streamContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var xDoc= XDocument.Parse(streamContents);
```